# Alternative to throwing/catching errors with async code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception, asynchronous, callback

I'm used to throwing an instance of some error class and having them be caught somewhere down the line in the app, to account for user error.

An example might be validating the username:

```
function validateUsername (username) {
    if (!/^[a-z0-9_-]{3,15}$/.test(username)) {
        throw new ValidationError('Please enter 3-15 letters, digits, -, and/or _.');
    }
}

$('#username').blur(function () {
    try {
        validateUsername($(this).val());
    } catch (x) {
        $('<p></p>').addClass('error').text(x).insertAfter(this);
    }
});
```

But now I'm realizing that I can't use these same practices for asynchronous calls. For example:

```
function checkUsernameAvailability (username) {
    $.get('/users/' + username).done(function () {
        // Done = user returned; therefore, username is unavailable
        // But I can't catch this error without resorting to something gross
        // like window.onerror
        throw new ValidationError('The username you entered is already in use.');
    });
}
```

I could make `checkUsernameAvailability` accept a callback and/or return a promise and have it execute said callback with the availability of the username.

```
$('#username').blur(function () {
    checkUsernameAvailability(username, function (available) {
        !available && alert('The username you entered is already in use.');
    });
});
```

But part of what makes exceptions so powerful is that they can bubble up the stack until they get caught, whereas if I had another function that called another function that called `checkUsernameAvailability`, I'd need to pass the result of this callback manually all the way until I get to the place where I want to handle it.

What are some of the alternative methods for passing errors up the stack? I can think of some of these, but none of them are as clean as native exceptions:

- Passing a flag, or the ValidationError instance, to a callback (Node.js approach could work too, passing an error or null as the first argument, and the data as the second); but then, if I don't want to handle it at that point in the stack, I need to pass the error up manually
- Or passing 2 callbacks to the `checkUsernameAvailability` function, a success callback and an error callback; this seems to have the same drawbacks as the previous point
- Triggering a "ValidationError" event so I can listen anywhere, but make sure to `return false;` in the handler so it doesn't execute higher in the stack; however, this pollutes the event namespace and could make it unclear as to which event listener will be executed first; plus, it's difficult to trace an event to its origin using the console

Comment: This is what Promises are for. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise  There are many libraries that will allow you to use them in es5

Comment: the function passed to "done" has closure that retained "username", so what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

in principal it is like this

```
function Exception (errcode) {
  this.code = errcode;
}

...

try {
  ...
  throw new Exception('alpha');
  ...
} catch (e) {
  if (e.code === {something}) {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, I recently took the first release of the Rogue game written for UNIX in C and rewrote it for javascript to work in a browser.  I used a technic called continuation to be able to wait for key entry by the user because in javascript the are no interrupts.

So I would have a piece of code like this:

```
void function f() {

  // ... first part

  ch = getchar();

  // ... second part

}
```

that would be transformed in

```
function f() {

  // ... first part

  var ch = getchar(f_cont1);

  return;
  // the execution stops here 

  function f_cont1 () {

    // ... second part
  }
}
```

the continuation is then stored to be reuse on a keypressed event.  With closures everything would be restarted where it stoped.